# Pandas rolling average of a columns of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, rolling-computation

I'm trying to calculate the rolling average of a column of `datetime` objects. In my scenario, the input data are the *last day below freezing* each year for ~100 years.

Ignoring the years, I want to take a rolling average over the month-day rows. The output would be the average last day below freezing over some window of years.

My final plot will be years on the x-axis and the rolling average of the last day below freezing on the y-axis.

Here is a minimal setup of rows I want to average over.

```
df = pd.Series(['1900-05-04','1901-05-03', ..., '1910-04-30'])
df = pd.to_datetime(df)

>>> df

87   1900-05-04
88   1901-05-03
89   1902-05-06
90   1903-05-01
91   1904-05-03
92   1905-04-29
93   1906-05-03
94   1907-05-03
95   1908-05-04
96   1909-04-30
97   1910-04-30
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Desired output (with or without the years) with a window size of two would be:

```
1   1901-05-04
2   1902-05-05
3   1903-05-04
4   1904-05-02
5   1905-05-01
6   1906-05-03
7   1907-05-04
8   1908-05-02
9   1909-04-30
10  1910-04-30
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? What is your expected output, and how does what you are getting differ?

Comment: You say you have the first day below freezing for 100 years, but you show 5 dates of the same year... please provide a more representative sample of your data, and your expected result.

Comment: Can you add expected results?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack! It should be taken as inspiration and mostly like there exist a better one as it’s not optimal

```py
pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame((df.loc[1:].dt.year, df.loc[1:].dt.month,
df.groupby(df.dt.month).transform(lambda d: d.dt.day.rolling(2).mean().round(0)).loc[1:].astype(int))).T.rename(columns={0:'year',1:'month',2:'day'}))
```

I group by month and took a rolling mean. I rebuilt the date by assembling the year, month and rolled day.

Results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. There remains however an issue. When I apply this to my larger dataset, I'm getting an `IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer` from this part: 

`ld_data.groupby(ld_data.dt.month).transform(lambda d: d.dt.day.rolling(2).mean().round(0)).loc[1:]` 

After checking, there are indeed some nan values amidst the data. The reason I suspect that this is happening is that the groupby month method ignores the index and there are some data that waver around the month boundary sometimes above and below. Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: For example, try running the algorithm on the sample data I've updated the question with.